# How to run an update on Autoprefixer's caniuse list

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, autoprefixer

I am running Autoprefixer in Sublime Text 3, and am now getting this error when saving CSS files:

> Autoprefixer Error:  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db

The problem I have is simple. I don't know where or how to run the given instruction. Is this done within ST3, or via Terminal on the Mac? And how is it done?

Would really appreciate a pointer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done from Terminal. All the action takes place in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Autoprefixer`, so go there first:

```sh
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/Autoprefixer
```

Next, we need to delete the old binaries, as at least my version of `npm` didn't want to overwrite them. This deletes `autoprefixer` and `browserslist`:

```sh
rm node_modules/.bin/*
```

Next, all you need to do is run

```sh
npm update
```

(again, from `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Autoprefixer` - *this is very important*) and you should be all set. When I ran it 10 minutes ago, the results were:

```
+ postcss@7.0.35
+ postcss-scss@2.1.1
+ autoprefixer@9.8.6
added 3 packages from 3 contributors, removed 8 packages, updated 9 packages and audited 24 packages in 1.07s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Your results may be different depending on when you run the command, as different versions might be available then.

Comment: thanks – i'm feeling quite stupid here, but i'm assuming your intsruction at the top of this is to enter `cd ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Autoprefixer` into terminal and hit enter? it's tripping up on the first space it encounters and giving me this: `~/Library/Application: No such file or directory`. obviously the file is there but the path is being broken. forgive me – terminal is something of a mystery at this end.

Comment: @mtm sorry, my bad. I just edited my answer. If you simply put double quotes around the whole path, it'll process the spaces correctly.

Comment: hmmm. it has, but still seems to think the directory isn't there: `-bash: cd: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Autoprefixer: No such file or directory`. i can see it in the finder though.

Comment: @mtm If you want to do some live troubleshooting, join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223173/64390006-troubleshooting and ping me.

Comment: thanks – that's really kind of you. i missed this over the weekend and may have missed you at said link, but this would be super-helpful if still possible.